# UEFI DUET does not boot Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, uefi

Am trying to boot Ubuntu 12.04 using DUET.
I have bootable DUET in one USB flash drive and i have bootable Ubuntu 12.04 in another USB flash drive.
After getting into DUET,Through Boot Maintenance Manager,i have selected EFI/boot/bootx64.efi and am getting GRUB command prompt.
How do i boot ubuntu using this command prompt now?
when i try root command means it is throwing "out of memory" error
Can you please help me on this?

Note:I have Windows XP and Ubuntu 32bit on my PC.that's why i would like to try "TRY UBUNTU WITHOUT INSTALLING" from USB flash drive

Comment: Can you provide more details about the physical computer, such as RAM, processor, make/model, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is a GRUB problem, not a DUET problem. (DUET seems to be working correctly, based on the description.) It sounds like GRUB isn't finding its configuration file, which is odd if this is a standard Ubuntu installation with its usual version of GRUB; but if you did anything unusual to isntall GRUB, it could be you need to re-visit the GRUB installation options. Also, Ubuntu normally installs GRUB to the ESP's `EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`. Thus, you might try launching that file rather than `EFI\boot\bootx64.efi`. The two files might actually be identical, but if they're not, using `EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` might work better.

Unfortunately, GRUB is *very* tricky to configure correctly. It works easily for many users only because most distributions include complex scripts that scan the system and create a configuration that works correctly. Instead of working on GRUB, you might consider using another EFI boot loader. [My Web page on this topic](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) covers the options. The easiest to get started with is likely to be my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) in conjunction with the EFI stub loader (which is built into 3.3.0 and later kernels). If you're using the original Ubuntu 12.04, it came with a 3.2.0 kernel, so the EFI stub loader won't work; but the 12.04.2 update comes with a later kernel that does have EFI stub loader support.

Comment: Hi RodSmith,Thanks for your reply.Am not trying to Install GRUB and i can see bootx64.efi and grubx64.efi under EFI\boot path.Am using 12.04.2 only..As you mentioned i shall try use rEFInd boot manager with EFI stub loader and let you know the feedback

Comment: Hi RodSmith,can i use Ubuntu 32bit OS(12.04.02 32bit) to Install rEFInd boot manager or Is it mandatory to have 64bit OS(12.04.02 64bit) only?

Comment: If you're installing the boot program as `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` on the ESP, then you can use anything -- 32-bit, 64-bit, or even a foreign architecture like PowerPC. You need to match the architecture if you register the boot loader with the EFI via `efibootmgr`, `bcfg`, or similar tools, though. My experience with DUET is that these tools don't work -- or more precisely, their effects disappear when you reboot. Thus, you'll need to store your boot program as `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`.